# Optimizing large Angular table grid

Tags: angular, performance

I am having performance issues when trying to display a grid of editable inputs. It starts to get really slow at around 200 rows and 10 columns. (using Angular 4.4)

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td *ngFor="let column of columns">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="column.columnType">
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="0">
        <input [(ngModel)]="row[column.index].value" ...>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="1">
        <select ...>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="2">
        <span ...>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="...">
        <div ...>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="15">
        <a href ...>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </td>
</tr>
```

There is a lot of time taken (according to the Chrome profiler - debugUpdateDirectives) in the switch statement as well as . Any ideas on how to reduce this?

Comment: Implement pagination and do the updates in batches. Since angular keeps tracks of all the updates, it will become more slow as the no of components increase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.Js Performance, large dataset, ng-repeat, html table with filters and two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035391/angular-js-performance-large-dataset-ng-repeat-html-table-with-filters-and-tw)

Comment: It's not a dupe of that as the framework is not the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably want to use `trackBy`. You can add this additional piece to each of your `*ngFor`'s to help Angular know whether or not each slice needs to be redrawn. It will use the value returned by `trackBy` to determine whether or not the row is dirty (i.e. `lastTrackByResult === currentTrackByResult`).

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows; trackBy: rowTrackByFunction">
```

And then in your controller:

```
rowTrackByFunction(index, item) {
   // You will want to return a unique primitive for angular to use as a comparison item
   // (string, number, etc.)
   return item.someUniqueIdentifier;
}
```

See this link for more info:

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

P.S. If the performance becomes really important you might consider using a pre-made table component that comes with built-in virtual scrolling. I would recommend NGX-Datable, which can easily handle thousands of rows by only drawing what the user can currently see. 
http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

Comment: You might also consider using Ag-Grid instead of ngx-datatable. In our team we looked through all available grid-frameworks for Angular and Ag-grid was by far the best, compared to material-datatable primeng-datatable and ngx-datatable. There is a whole bunch of optimizations that comes with Ag-Grid which you can see here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-performance/ but it is a bit hard to setup, if you don't want inputs to have input-listeners all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by wrapping the logic with the *ngFor inside into an OnPush component. This makes 300 * 10 inputs display super fast!

Comment: OnPush fixed it for me.  trackby made little difference on a table with 1000 rows.