# Import of Angular build .js files conflicts with React .js

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, wagtail

I'm extending the Wagtail admin site with Angular-based components.

The existing site is already importing React-based js files.
If I remove the React import `<script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/vendor.js' %}"></script>` and `<script src="{% static 'wagtailadmin/js/wagtailadmin.js' %}"></script>`, it works.

The question is, how both Angular and React can co-exists in the same site?

Here below the error I'm getting from the JS console:

[image: JavaScript console]

Versions used:

- Angular 6.1.10
- Wagtail 2.2.2

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849114/can-angular-and-react-play-together

Comment: @kev No, because I'm not developing both React and Angular components. React components are already provided by Wagtail and packed into .js files. What I need to know is how to avoid that the two goes in conflict, maybe there is a different way to export/build angular files